# Why isn't this concatenating as expected?

Tags: perl, concatenation

I'm trying to lean some Perl and doing a few simple exercises to get myself used to it.

One of the exercises is manipulating strings and i've written the below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Please enter some text..\n";
my $string =<STDIN>;

my $string_reverse = reverse $string;
print "Reversed: $string_reverse\n";

my $string_length = length $string;
print "Length: $string_length\n";

my $string_upper = uc $string;
print "Uppercase: $string_upper\n";

my $string_lower = lc $string;
print "Lowercase: $string_lower\n";
print "Enter a second bit of text\n";

my $second_string = <STDIN>;
print $string . $second_string;
```

This produces the following output.

```
Please enter some text..
test
Reversed:
tset
Length: 5
Uppercase: TEST

Lowercase: test

Enter a second bit of text
123
test
123
```

I expected the concatenated text to be shown as:

> test123

Why is it showing instead on a new line every time?

Comment: you need to `chomp $string` and `chomp $second_string`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my $string =<STDIN>;
```

Reads in a string, including a newline.

Try using `chomp` to trim the newline off.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your example to run but I'll venture an answer anyway. If you're getting your string from `<STDIN>` you have a newline in your string. These probably need to be removed with `chomp($your_str)` for each of the strings.